# Can I join a local personal workstation to a Google Cloud Active Directory Domain?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, active-directory, domaincontroller

My company's members all work remotely and there is no central office or HQ. They are interested in a cloud AD to create and manage group policy's. I created one using these steps in Google Cloud services [LINK](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/cloud-managed-ad#10). I have a VPC, A Domain and a VM joined to the domain with Active directory installed. I am fairly new to this and looking for a way to now join a local workstation to the Domain so it talks to the Active Directory I created. All the documentation I am finding is for joining other Google Cloud VMs to the Domain Controller.

Comment: Yes, you can. However, only consider this if you are using a VPN to connect to Google Cloud.

Answer (score 1):

As John mentioned, as a best practice it's recommended to [use VPN tunnels to secure LDAP traffic](https://cloud.google.com/managed-microsoft-ad/docs/best-practices#use_vpn_tunnels_to_secure_ldap_traffic), you can [connect to your Managed Microsoft AD domain with Google Cloud Hybrid Connectivity products](https://cloud.google.com/managed-microsoft-ad/docs/connect-to-active-directory-domain#via-vpn), like Cloud VPN or Cloud Interconnect. You can configure the connection from your on-premises or other network to an authorized network of Managed Microsoft AD domain. I share with you a document to configure an [HA VPN in GCP to a peer VPN Gateway](https://cloud.google.com/network-connectivity/docs/vpn/how-to/creating-ha-vpn)

Comment: Thank you for the response. When I went to create the GCP VPN it was requiring a remote peer ip address. I think it needs an already established VPN to work, it basically just "hooks" onto it. Is there anyway around this? This company does not use any vpns or network/servers currently. We wanted Google Cloud to be that for us.